# Cotorsion-freeness in uncountable products of abelian groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, abelian-groups

An abelian group $A$ is *cotorsion* provided that whenever $A \leq G$ with $G$ abelian and $G/A$ is
torsion-free, we have $G \cong A \oplus B$ for some $B \leq  G$. An abelian group $A$ is
*cotorsion-free* if it contains no non-trivial cotorsion subgroup.

It seems that $\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$ is cotorsion-free.

1. What about an uncountable direct product like $\mathbb{Z}^{\mathfrak{c}}$? Is this group cotorsion-free?
2. More generally, if $G_i$, $i \in I$ are slender abelian groups, must $\prod_{i\in I}G_i$ be cotorsion-free?

Comment: There exist non split abelian extensions with kernel $\mathbf{Z}$ and quotient $\mathbf{Z}[1/2]$, so $\mathbf{Z}$ is not "cotorsion" in the above sense. Hence no group with $\mathbf{Z}$ as direct factor is cotorsion. In $\mathbf{Z}^X$ for arbitrary $X$, every nontrivial subgroup has $\mathbf{Z}$ as quotient, hence as direct factor, so no nontrivial subgroup is cotorsion. So $\mathbf{Z}^X$ is indeed cotorsion-free.

Comment: @YCor Most of this seems clear but why is it that every nontrivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^X$ has $\mathbb{Z}$ as a quotient?

Comment: @JKT. Let $H$ be a nonzero subgroup. Take a nonzero element $f\in H$. There exists $x\in X$ such that $f_x\neq 0$. Then consider the homomorphism $H\to\mathbf{Z}$, $g\mapsto g_x$: it is nonzero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, more is true.

Every direct product of cotorsion-free abelian groups is cotorsion-free. This is clear because the cotorsion-free abelian groups are precisely those that have no nonzero homomorphisms from any cotorsion group.

This answers the question, since slender abelian groups are cotorsion-free.